# How to get weekly, monthly, yearly report using react chart?

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

[I want to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjxDA.png)

I want to create a chart using React. I have data in JSON file. I want to put week, month & year in the option tag inside the select tag like this picture and when someone selects week it will show the weekly report, clicking on a month will show the monthly report.
How do I do this?